# ffmpeg - how to use vstack and pad?

Tags: ffmpeg

This function puts 2 videos top bottom

```
ffmpeg -i input0 -i input1 -filter_complex vstack=inputs=2 output
```

How can I add some padding in between? And how can I stack 3 videos instead? Something like this line

```
ffmpeg -i input0 -i input1 -i input2 -filter_complex vstack=inputs=2 --padding-between-input 100,0 output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pad each video except the first.

e.g. with 3 videos and padding of 100 pixels,

`ffmpeg -i input0 -i input1 -i input2 -filter_complex "[1]pad=iw:ih+100:0:100[v1];[2]pad=iw:ih+100:0:100[v2];[0][v1][v2]vstack=inputs=3" output`

e.g. with 2 videos and padding of 100 pixels,

`ffmpeg -i input0 -i input1 -filter_complex "[1]pad=iw:ih+100:0:100[v1];[0][v1]vstack=inputs=2" output`

Comment: thank you! I have trouble trying to make it work for 2 inputs now. How do I read the syntax? Id assume the value 100 in the code is the padding. What is [1], [v1]? What is [0][v1][v2] ? This is my code for 2 videos ffmpeg -i action.avi -i action.avi -filter_complex "[1]pad=iw:ih+10:0:10[v1];[2]pad=iw:ih+10:0:10[v2];[v1][v2]vstack=inputs=2" out.avi

Comment: [1] refers to the original stream from the second input (ffmpeg counts from zero). These are linklabels. See https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-syntax-1 for a technical description. See edited answer for two inputs